# BigInt operator+ function?

Tags: c++, bigint

I've been trying to work on the operator+ function but it doesn't seem to work..
Not sure what is wrong :s

BigInt.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using std::cout;

#ifndef BIGINT_H
#define BIGINT_H

class BigInt
{
//input and output operators
   friend istream & operator >> (istream &, BigInt &);
   friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const BigInt &);

//overloaded operators
   BigInt operator + (BigInt &, BigInt &);

public:
   BigInt(); //default constructor
   BigInt(int); //initializes array with user-specified numbers

  // BigInt operator +(const BigInt &); //???

   void display(); //prints array

private:
   static const int CAPACITY = 40;
   int Digits[CAPACITY]; //stores all digits

};
#endif
```

BigInt.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BigInt.h"
using std::cout;

BigInt::BigInt()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
      Digits[i] = 0;
}

BigInt::BigInt(int InitNum)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
      Digits[i] = 0;

   for (int i = 0; InitNum != 0 ; ++i)
   {
      Digits[i] = (InitNum % 10);
      InitNum = InitNum / 10;
   }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------
BigInt operator +(BigInt & lhs, BigInt & rhs)
{
   BigInt results;
   int carry = 0;

   for (int i = 39 ; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      int indexAddition = lhs.Digits[i] + rhs.Digits[i] + carry;
      if (indexAddition > 9)
         carry = 1;
      else
         carry = 0;

      results.Digits[i] %= 10;
   }

   return results;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
bool BigInt::operator == (const BigInt & rhs)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
   {
      if (Digits[i] != rhs.Digits[i])
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
ostream & operator << (ostream & cout, const BigInt& a)
{
   for(int i = a.CAPACITY - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
      cout << a.Digits[i];

   cout << "\n";

   return cout;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & cin,  BigInt& a)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < a.CAPACITY; i++)
      cin >> a.Digits[i];

   return cin;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------
void BigInt::display()
{
   for(int i = CAPACITY - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      cout << Digits[i];

   cout << "\n";
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include "BigInt.h"

int main()
{
   BigInt object1(45756369);
   BigInt object2(47435892);

   cout << object1;
   object2.display();

   BigInt object3 = object1 + object2;

   cout << object3;

   return 0;
}
```

When I tried using

```
 BigInt operator +(const BigInt &);
```

, which was implemented this way:

```
BigInt::operator +(const BigInt &a)
{
   BigInt result;

   for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
      result = Digits[i] + a.Digits[i];

   return result;
}
```

I would get this error:

```
BigInt.cpp: In function âBigInt& operator+(const BigInt&)â:
BigInt.cpp:36:23: error: âCAPACITYâ was not declared in this scope
BigInt.cpp:37:16: error: âDigitsâ was not declared in this scope
BigInt.h:50:23: error: âint BigInt::Digits [40]â is private
BigInt.cpp:37:30: error: within this context
BigInt.cpp:34:11: warning: reference to local variable âresultâ returned [enabled by default]
```

And when I use

```
BigInt operator +(BigInt & lhs, BigInt & rhs)
{
   BigInt results;
   int carry = 0;

   for (int i = 39 ; i >= 0; i--)
   {
      int indexAddition = lhs.Digits[i] + rhs.Digits[i] + carry;

      if (indexAddition > 9)
         carry = 1;
      else
         carry = 0;

      results.Digits[i] %= 10;
   }

   return results;
}


In file included from BigInt.cpp:9:0:
BigInt.h:31:39: error: âBigInt BigInt::operator+(BigInt&, BigInt&)â must take either zero or one     argument
BigInt.h: In function âBigInt operator+(BigInt&, BigInt&)â:
BigInt.h:50:23: error: âint BigInt::Digits [40]â is private
BigInt.cpp:50:27: error: within this context
BigInt.h:50:23: error: âint BigInt::Digits [40]â is private
BigInt.cpp:50:43: error: within this context
BigInt.h:50:23: error: âint BigInt::Digits [40]â is private
BigInt.cpp:57:11: error: within this context
```

Why? 
Thank you!

Comment: Please don't post code dumps. They aren't helpful to future visitors at all.

Comment: But it works when the parameters are *not* `const`, correct?

Comment: It compiles, but it doesn't add...

Comment: How does this even compile? I get errors in the first code block...

Comment: I edited the code a little to this `BigInt BigInt::operator + (BigInt & rhs)
{

   BigInt results;

   for(int i = CAPACITY - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      results = Digits[i] + rhs.Digits[i];

   return results;
}` and it gave me this: 0000000000000000000000000000000045756369
0000000000000000000000000000000047435892
0000000000000000000000000000000000000011

Comment: Please consider the advice offered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: You should pass by const reference when not modifying them. Anyway, my preferred implementation of `operator+` is `BigInt operator+(BigInt lhs, const BigInt &rhs) {return lhs += rhs;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `operator+` function isn't a member of `BigInt` so it cannot access the private members thereof. You should declare it as a friend of the class instead:

```
friend BigIn operator +(BigInt &, BigInt &);
```

Comment: Alright.. I did that and now I am getting `BigInt.cpp:45:9: warning: reference to local variable âresultsâ returned [enabled by default]`

Comment: @TongZhang The error message is very straight-forward. You're returning by reference a local variable which is dangerous because the variable won't outlive the function call. Why not return by value instead?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the **results.Digits[i]** in line 4 of

```
BigInt BigInt::operator+(const BigInt &a)
{
   BigInt result;

   for(int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
      result.Digits[i] = Digits[i] + a.Digits[i];

   return result;
}
```